# angular material - md-no-ink not workd, how can I disable the animation of the md-tabs

Tags: angularjs

How can I disable the animation of the md-tabs in angular meterial, md-no-ink not workd.

```
<md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" md-no-ink=""> 
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>          
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>          
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>      
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using md-no-bar along with md-no-ink

Comment: @Vikash I need disable the animation of the md-tab, in the header I don't need to disable.